# question regarding the process of feature selection, model building and k fold cross validation

Tags: cross-validation

I have a question regarding the process of  feature selection, model building and k fold cross validation.

### I have a  forty features and 200 records data sets. I want to select down to 10-12 features and build  a  model maybe linear regression. Here is my understand of  the whole  process.

1. In the beginning use all the data, calculate the correlation matrix to find large pair wise correlation and drop some feature highly correlated features
2. Use all your data, build different models  and use certain measures like R square or  Root mean square error  to evaluate among different models
3. Split you data and do a k fold cross validation  to verify if there is over-fitting in your model  to evaluate your model. Average the error from each cv  as the overall error, compare different model  with this overall error.
4. Select  the model

   ### 5.  Refit the model with all the data.

But  I feel there is some flaw, can someone point out for me. In step 2, my model see all the data.
 Should I use K-fold CV from beginning?  But K fold CV is for model evaluation. Each step there will be a different set of features.  I understand , feature selection, model building and CV. But how to connect them  and in what sequence I'm still not clear.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Do feature selection inside the cross-validation loop. By this I mean that in each round of the cross-validation procedure, the features to be used should be selected using only the training data.

This said, there are ways to do feature selection that will likely perform better than thresholding correlations, such as [the lasso](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)). Consult your favorite machine-learning textbook for a review of feature-selection methods.